# Two questions about terminologies in computer cluster

Tags: cluster-computing

I am a layman to computer science, I have some questions about terminology of computer cluster here.

- A cluster has 300 nodes.

Does it mean the cluster has 300 computers?

- The cores of CPU is using hyperthreading, so there can be a total of 16 threads running simultaneously.

What are hyperthreading or threads here? A stream of data or logic?

Comment: I really should down-vote, but if you go read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) I promise I wont.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hyperthreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) is an Intel technology for managing simultaneous multithreading. It doesn't necessarily have anything to do with cluster computing.

A [thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) is as a single running task that can be executed asynchronously from everything else. So depending on what kind of a processor your computer has it may be able to execute a different amount of things asynchronously.

Meanwhile, nodes in clusters are usually separate computers. However, they can be Virtual Machines as well. Within some contexts I have seen a single processor core regarded as a node too (in this case one machine with 2 cores will have 2 nodes on it). This kind of depends on the framework and what exactly you're doing.

But usually with cluster computing you have a given task that can be scaled, and every entity that does it is called a node.